# Override comment.tpl.php file with theme

Tags: theming

**Objective**:
Override comment.tpl.php file output in drupal core modules.

**Assumption**:
My best guess is that I need to create a comment-[type].tpl.php file in my themes folder.

**Requirements**:

- template.php can not be used
- need to replace default comment.tpl.php html output

**Questions**:

- how do i find the so called type of the comment for the tpl file?
- is this the best way to change the html output of the file?
- is there another way to change the output with the type or using template.php?

**Links**: http://drupal.org/node/190815

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to override Drupal's default comment.tpl.php file by copying it from /modules/comment into your theme directory. From there, edit the file as needed. Then clear the cache (on the Admin > Site configuration > Performance), so that the theme cache will get rebuilt and your new theme file will get recognized.

You would only need to rename comment.tpl.php to comment-[type].tpl.php, if you wanted to override comment theming differently for different node types.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I have cleared caches and i get nothing. Restarted PC, cleared browser cache and dns

Comment: could i be having issues because a module may be overriding the comment.tpl too? I thought themes have higher override

Comment: Try installing the Devel Themer module, which should provider you more information on what theme files are being used for different areas of the site: https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

Comment: awesome thanks. i know this should work but im just having a time with it.